# How to fetch next 5 records based on given index in pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas, pandas-datareader

I want to fetch the next 5 records after the specific index.

For example, this is my dataframe:

```
    Id  Name        code
    1   java         45
    2   python       78
    3   c            65
    4   c++          25
    5   html         74
    6   css          63
    7   javascript   45 
    8   php          44
    9   Ajax         88
    10  jQuery       92
```

When i provide the index value as `3` then the code must fetch the next 5 values from `3`. So the result should look like:

```
   Id  Name        code
    3   c            65
    4   c++          25
    5   html         74
    6   css          63
    7   javascript   45
```

I do not understand how to do this. My code is not working as I want it to.

I am using this code for fetching the next 5 records:

```
data = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(indexid):+5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
idx = df.reset_index()['Id'].eq(8).idxmax()
ranges = np.r_[idx:idx+5] % len(df)

df.iloc[ranges]
```

Output:

```
   Id    Name  code
7   8     php    44
8   9    Ajax    88
9  10  jQuery    92
0   1    java    45
1   2  python    78
```

Comment: hey its working fine for top records but when i am passing bottom values like index value is 8 then it is only giving 3 records in result  but what i want is it should return remaining 3 records with top 2 records.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, need also add `5` to first position, so use:

```
#if Id is not index
#df = df.set_index('Id')

p = df.index.get_loc(3)
df = df.iloc[p:p+5]
print (df)
          Name  code
Id                  
3            c    65
4          c++    25
5         html    74
6          css    63
7   javascript    45
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code

```
idx=df.index.get_indexer([3])[0]
df.iloc[idx:idx+5]
Out[9]: 
          Name  code
Id                  
3            c    65
4          c++    25
5         html    74
6          css    63
7   javascript    45
```

Comment: when I am providing index value as 8 its giving only 3 records but what I want is when i provide index value as 8 its should give last 3 records with top 2 records .